# Overriding methods of custom class. Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

```
- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    [super setFrame:frame];

    // code...
}
```

That's basically what I was doing to override standard methods of classes in Objective-C.
I have created a custom class myClass that has a variable called style NSInteger myStyle.

I tried the same thing:

```
- (void)setMyStyle:(NSInteger)myStyle
{
    [super setMyStyle:myStyle];

    // code...
}
```

But it's not working, since it can't find this method:

```
[super setMyStyle:myStyle];
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What does "not working" mean exactly?

Comment: What do you mean by "...has a variable called style NSInteger myStyle"?  If it is actually a variable (and not a method or a property with automatically generated methods) then there is nothing to override since there isn't a method.

Answer (score 1):

> But it's not working, since it can't find this method:

As you are calling `[super setMyStyle:myStyle];` your super class must have a method named `setMyStyle`.

EDIT:

> I have created a custom class myClass that has a variable called style NSInteger myStyle.

As you have a variable called `myStyle`, you need to create setter and getter for it. For this you need create methods or use `@property`/`@synthesize`.

Or no need to create an iVar, you can directly create a property for `myStyle`.

Comment: He already said he has this method; I believe the issue is that the Xcode autocomplete can't find it because his superclass doesn't declare it in the interface file.

Comment: XCode automatically creates the setMyStyle: method. What i want to do is to override it. Every time i set the variable myStyle using setMyStyle: i want for it to actually be set and also to do something else.

Comment: XCode doesn't create setMyStyle for iVar, it creates for property.

Comment: And kindly let us know, your class is called `myClass`, and what is its superClass, Does your superclass has `myStyle`?

Comment: I think i have this messed. It's actually a property of the class. And it's an NSObject so there's nothing higher in the hierarchy.

Comment: I just got this figured out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have your method declared in the header file for your parent class:

```
//ParentClass.h

@interface ParentClass : ItsParentClass {

}

- (void)setMyStyle:(NSInteger)myStyle;
```

And that you #include the header in your subclass

```
//YourSubClass.h
#import "ParentClass.h"

@interface YourSubClass : ParentClass {

}
```

That way when you call -[super setMyStyle:] the compiler expects super's class (ParentClass) to have the setMyStyle method and you won't get the error.

```
#import "YourSublass.h"
@implementation YourSublass

- (void)setMyStyle:(NSInteger)myStyle
{
    [super setMyStyle:myStyle];

    // code...
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Another reason i could think of is, probably you forgot to include the parent class in your header class?

```
@interface CustomClass : ParentClass{

}
```

Hope this helps..